# websocket is closed when loading Primefaces push / atmosphere example

Tags: sockets, netbeans, primefaces, glassfish, atmosphere

I followed this tutorial to do a simple counter application in a primefaces project:
http://blog.eisele.net/2012/09/primefaces-push-with-atmosphere-on.html

When the page with the counter is loaded, I get an error msg saying that the websocket gets closed improperly?

I wonder if this could have to do with the config of Glassfish? I have enabled comet support and websockets, but I may have missed other settings?

[config:
GlassFish 3.1.2
Atmosphere 1.0.1
Primefaces 3.4.1
Netbeans 7.2]

Comment: thx. Yet the blog post mentioned in my question used GlassFish. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it, I hope it will help others.

Instead of trying to enable comet via the GlassFish admin panel (localhost:4848), visit the services panel in Netbeans, right-click on the Glassfish server, and tick "enable comet". Solved. I suppose Eclipse has the same kind of UI.

All of this would probably not have happened if I had written the command-line version to enable comet suggested in the blog post mentioned in my original question. But I'm no command line afficionado yet...